# turn this into a jquery function?

Tags: jquery

I am using the code below to do pagination on a table (please do not suggest any prebuilt ones)

```
function tablejax(url, start, count) {
    $('#tablejaxButton').attr("disabled", "true");
    $('#tablejaxOverlay').fadeIn('slow');
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        data: "start="+start+"&count="+count+"&identifier="+$('#tablejaxButton').val(),
        success: function(data){
            setTimeout(function(){
                $('#myTable tbody').append(data);
                $('#myTable tr td div').slideDown('slow');
                $("html:not(:animated),body:not(:animated)").animate({
                    scrollTop: $('body').attr("scrollHeight")
                    }, 1000 );
                $("table").trigger("update");
            }, 1000);
            setTimeout(function(){
                $('#tablejaxOverlay').fadeOut('slow');
                $('#tablejaxButton').removeAttr('disabled');
            }, 1000);
        }
    });
}
```

however i am currently calling it through

```
$('#tablejaxButton').click(function() {
        tablejax(this.name,  tcount, 20);
        tcount = tcount+20;
    })
```

there are a few problems with this,
but the ones i want to change are.

I want to be able to call `$('#tableID').tablejax('url', 'identifier', 'count');`
eg `$('#tableUsers').tablejax('get_members.php', 27, 20);`

it would automatically attach an onclick event to `#tableUsersButton` (tableID + Button)

i want the function itself to keep track of where we should start from,
currently i am using

```
tcount = 20;  
//do stuff  
tcount = tcount +20;
```

which is not ideal.

what is the easiest way to do this?

note: the function should make an assumption that the `count` that is passed into it has already been loaded into the table, eg if you call `$('#tableUsers').tablejax('get_members.php', 27, 20);` then the first 20 rows would already be loaded into the table via server side processing.

---

**Update**
To simplify my question.

I need to be able to call `$('#tableID).tablejax(--initial params here--);`
on document ready,

this would basically get a function ready by filling out some default params (eg identifier, url, ect)
this would also add on onclick event handler to `$('#tableIDButton')` which when clicked would call something like `$('#tableIDButton').tablejax('next');`

this approach is used as sometimes i need to call the pagination using another trigger.

all i need to know is

- How to register a function in jquery: **Answered**
- How to register the click event when the function is called **Answered:** *Turns out I can register a click even from anywhere not just document ready*
- How to call an 'action' in the function when it is not the initial call
   *(initial call should use the parameters, subsequent calls should call an 'internal function)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the extend() function to add functions to the jQuery object:

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    tablejax: function(url, start, count) {
        $('#tableIDButton').click(function() {
            $('#tableID').tablejax(url, start+20, count); // just pass on the variables
        }
    } // put comma here if you want to add more functions
});
// to run the function on document ready:
$(function() {
    $('#tableID').tablejax(...);
}
```

Then you should be able to call your function like you wanted. You obviously still need to call it inside a click event.

**Update:**

Updated my example to answer question 2 and 3. To fetch the next rows you could call the same function again recursively, like in the example.

Btw, I don't see how my example "pollutes the jQuery namespace", as it's taken from jQuery's own documentation.

Comment: Hi there,
This is close.
However i want to call `$('#tableID').tablejax(blablabla);`
on document ready.
When i call that, it should register a click event on `$('#tableIDButton')` that calls something like $('#tableID').tablejax('next');

which will grab the next few rows

Comment: I may be wrong, but i was always told that extending the jquery object with your own functions pollutes it as if you have internal functions (eg update, remove, change_colour) they may conflict with others, however using 0xAF's method your internal functions are just that, internal.

also, i dont really want to have to pass in the paramaters each time, hence why i want to be able to just call tablejax('next');

I guess I could always use just tablejax(); and if there are no params then use what was passed in in the options array...

Comment: There are two problems here. 1) You can't have two functions with the same name, but with different parameters/implementations. 2) The `tablejax('next');` function wouldn't make sense, because it's called on a HTML element, and thus won't know anything about the previous queries. So there's no information to calculate what's to come next. Unless that's stored in the button of course, but you would need to give the function a different name for when you just want the next rows.

Answer (score 3):

i guess this will help:
http://www.google.bg/search?q=jquery+plugin+tutorial

basicly you would write something like this:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.tablejax = function(options) {
        this = $(this); // this is the element on which we called the func
        this.tcount+=20;
        // do something here...
    }
})(jQuery);
```

save this to jquery.tablejax.js and then call it in html after jquery.js

you'll need to implement the function and then you can call it on every element or selector.

Comment: thankyou, this is almost exactly what i need (and improves on Stians answer as it does not polute the jquery namespace)

Please see my update for the other two points.

Comment: can i get away with calling `$.fn.tablejax = function(options) { --blabla-- $('#' + this.id + 'Button').click(-- blabla --); }`